# How to know which of the QGraphicsItems is being moved at the moment?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots, qgraphicsitem

I have `QGraphicsScene` on which some custom `QGraphicsItems` are displayed. Those items are described in class `MeasurePoint`, which inherits from `QGraphicsItem`. They are also stored in `QList`, so each item has it's index. They are added to the scene like so:

```
void MeasureSpline::addNode(qreal xPos, qreal yPos, QGraphicsScene *scene)
{
    MeasurePoint *point = new MeasurePoint(xPos, yPos, points.size());
    points.append(point);
    point->setPoint(scene);
}
```

where `points` is:

```
QList<MeasurePoint*> points;
```

and each `MeasurePoint` is constructed like so:

```
MeasurePoint::MeasurePoint(qreal a, qreal b, int c)
{
    xPos = a;
    yPos = b;
    index = c;
    movable = false;
    selected = false;
}
```

and `setPoint()` is:

```
void MeasurePoint::setPoint(QGraphicsScene *scene)
{
    scene->addItem(this);
}
```

I have a method for setting items movable. If i use this method, the items become movable and i'm happy with the result. But my current goal is to know which of the items is being moved at the moment. Can it be done? How? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: offtopic: `setPoint(scene);` or should it be `setScene(scene);`?

Comment: @MarekR it is as it is, no mistake here. This function adds MeasurePoint to the scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make the QGraphicsItem make reacting on Position Changes like this:

```
item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | 
QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
```

then you can reimplement the Change-Event and emit a Signal from there:

```
QVariant Item::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
if (change == ItemPositionChange  && scene() || change == ItemScenePositionHasChanged)  // either during mouseMoveEvent or when Dropped again
{
    emit itemMoved();  // connect to other SLOT and cast QObject::sender() or something here....
}
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Edit:

Untested Code for Receiving Method:

```
void MyClass::onItemMoved()
{

MesurePoint* item = dynamic_cast<MesurePoint*>(QObject::sender());

if (item != NULL)
 {
   int index = points.IndexOf(item);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to change that itemChange() function so it returns index of item that is being moved? I have index field in MeasurePoint class which is assigned upon creation new MeasurePoint object. Can i somehow acces that field in that function?

Comment: the return-Value is not the thing you are interested in here. It just passes the Event on to the QGraphicsItem. I Dont know what you mean with the "index of item". Is it the Index of the Item within the List it is holding? I Cant image a Way the Item is aware of this index but you could iterate through that list in the receiving function until you find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch (mouse press and move) events [sent to `QGraphicsItem` from `QGraphicsScene`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#events) and then - for example - emit a signal you can connect to.